# Regex: At least one uppercase char, one lowercase char, one digit and nothing else

Tags: regex

I would to have a regex for password matching to make sure password contains:

1. at least one digit
2. at least one uppercase alphabet
3. at least one lowercase alphabet
4. nothing else (only digits and numbers)

size is at least 6 and at most 15 characters

I tried this regex `^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,15}$` but it doesn't apply check #4 and matches a password that includes a special character, too.

Some other questions are available that address the question for abscense of some explicit letters. As you can see in the answer I accepted, the regex is not close to what I was looking for.

Comment: If you happen to be writing a password validation script, please do not make these the requirements. See https://xkcd.com/936/ for reasons why.

Comment: What are the good requirements ? I dom't think having one capital letter and one digit makes a password hard to remember.

Comment: Password length is very important. A 6 character minimum is too low. Source: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29836/what-are-good-requirements-for-a-password You also need to avoid incentivizing your users to reuse old passwords and/or use easily guessed passwords such as Password1.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.{6,15}` you're specifying "any character from 6 to 15 times". To restrict to "only digits and numbers" change the `.` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lfgL85/1